# Why this extra padding of the value field in class jsr166e.Striped64.Cell?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

In a class introduced as part of the JSR166, the author uses so called padding to pad the single value field of the Striped64.Cell class.

Here is an excerpt of that class:

```
/**
 * Padded variant of AtomicLong supporting only raw accesses plus CAS. The value field is placed
 * between pads, hoping that the JVM doesn't reorder them.
 * <p/>
 * JVM intrinsics note: It would be possible to use a release-only form of CAS here, if it were
 * provided.
 */
static final class Cell {
  volatile long p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
  volatile long value;
  volatile long q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6;

  ...
```

The author then uses CAS to modify the value atomically.

In the Striped64 class, the author also uses Unsafe to access two other fields but does not apply any of such padding.

My question is: Why would one need to do such a thing, introduce 14 redundant fields for padding off a single value field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The padding is there to prevent the cache line on which the `value` field is to be shared - otherwise the value may have to re-fetched from memory just because something else on the cache line requires the whole line to be invalidated. So the goal is performance improvement.

To make things easier, Java 8 has introduced the [`@Contended` annotation](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/142) which does the same thing under the hood, except that it is handled by the JVM itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that it is the correct one, but why the extra q0...q6 as the overall size of p0..p6 + value is already 64 bytes, which in my understanding would perfectly fit into a single cache line? Is it to accomodate other architectures that implement longer cache lines?

Comment: @silkentrance it's going to use 2 cache lines. If you only have p0, p1..., p6, value, you may well end up with p0-p6 on one cache line, with some other data, and value on another line, with other data.

Answer (score 6):

While I do agree with assylias's answer, I think it requires a bit of explanation.

**Why is a cache miss important?**

Because reading from main memory is much slower then the one from a cache. If you have a variable that needs to be used often getting it to cache is important. Also if this variable shares the same cache with other variables, you could have a case when this whole cache line could be invalidated.

Consider the example when variable1 lives on the same cache with variable2. variable1 is use by thread1 and variable2 is used by thread2. Because they live on the same cache line, if there is an update of variable2 and thread1 needs to use variable1 it needs to drop the cache line(*even if it does not use this variable!*) and read from main memory. This is called **false sharing**.

**Why there are actually 7 more longs?**

If an only if JVM does not decide to re-reorder the memory, then it does not matter where you start reading this variable from, (you could read it from the 3-rd, out of 8 "cache rows" ) - you will still end up with one single value in the cache line. So, no matter were you start reading from, only one value that is important to you will be in the cache line, thus no possibility of a "cache miss" of "false sharing."

P.S. That is why size of Java objects are divisible by 8.